# DataSerializable - serialize and deserialize two dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, serialization, deserialization, hazelcast

There are methods like *writeDoubleArray* and so on in *ObjectDataOutput* interface. Of course arrays can be of any dimension and in my case there are some 2D double arrays. How to serialize and then deserialize those? Or maybe because of the way Java handles 2D arrays (not really contiguous blocks in memory) I need to represent a 2D array as 1D one? I mean because of the performance I shouldn't really serialize 2D arrays. Just wrap it into utility object and store like this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the other dimensions yourself first, like the following snippet:

```
public static class Foo implements DataSerializable {

    private double[][] multiDimArray;

    @Override
    public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out)
            throws IOException {

        int firstDim = multiDimArray.length;
        out.writeInt(firstDim);
        for (int i = 0; i < firstDim; i++) {
            out.writeDoubleArray(multiDimArray[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void readData(ObjectDataInput in)
            throws IOException {

        int firstDim = in.readInt();
        multiDimArray = new double[firstDim][];
        for (int i = 0; i < firstDim; i++) {
            multiDimArray[i] = in.readDoubleArray();
        }
    }
}
```

That way it is possible two write any depth of array into a stream. You might be able to abstract that a bit away into two methods (read/write) for easier / more convenient use.